# Can I unlock Mac folders from a USB stick?

Tags: mac, macbook, unlock, directory

I use a Macbook. The folders appear to be locked with a lock icon( like Music, Video etc.). The folders like documents seem to be working fine. I can't do anything on my mac as it is not booting but i need to take the data out of it. Can I do it from a Ubuntu Live USB stick?

Comment: make sure they are not encrypted by the mac os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Slipstream](https://askubuntu.com/users/13003/slipstream) has answered you can use root privileges to access and copy the contents through terminal. All you have to do is boot from a Ubuntu live USB/CD and use following commands:

1. Open terminal via `Applications > Accessories > Terminal`; use `sudo su` to gain root user privileges and `ls /media/MacOSDrive` to list the contents. After MacOSDrive you can append `/Documents/` or any such directory name to list out their contents.
2. Once you are sure about the contents you need to copy use `sudo cp <source drive, say /media/MacOSDrive/Documents> -av <destination drive, say /media/an_external_drive>`, where `a` stands for all contents and `v` for verbose mode, which lists out what is being copied file by file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked perfect. Managed to copy everything without a problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu can access HFS+ which Mac uses. If you run:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

(I assume Gnome desktop), then you may get write access to the partition(s) and can then retrieve your data. I suggest you make a copy and put it somewhere safe.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have the right permissions to access them. You can still get at them using sudo though.

So say if you wanted to get into /media/MacOSDrive/Music/ or something then type:

```
cd /media/MacOSDrive/
ls
```

And you should see the folders listed that you can't get into. Try getting into the music directory:

```
cd Music
```

And it will say no in some way, then use sudo,

```
sudo cd Music
```

Then you should be able to get in, use *ls* to see the files in there.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1502964) will solve the problem for you. Just follow the steps listed in comment three. This is the same solution I used when I had this problem on my macbook. It's a more permanent solution then going through the terminal as root all the time.